# Spring data repository and rest controller: end point mixing & overriding

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest, spring-restcontroller

It is fairly common to expose the following endpoints for REST resources

```
@GET customers/ ==> list of customers
@POST customers/ ==> add a customer
@Get customers/:id ==> specific info of customer
@PUT customers/:id ==> override a customer
@PATCH customers/:id ==> update customer
```

Spring data rest repository handles this very well.

But if I'd like to add custom end points like

@GET customers/recent ==> retrieve customers recently visited 
@GET customers/:id/photo ===> all photos belonging to that customer

**Is there a way to add to the existing set of endpoints?**

Of course, we can repeat all the idiomic code in a `@RestController` annotated class, but that would be very repetitive for 10+ resources.

What I am looking for is like this

```
class CustomerController{
    // all @GET, @POST, @PUT, @PATCH methods are already generated, like a data rest repository

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{customerId}/photo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Collection<Photo> getAllPhotos(){
        ...
    }

    // it is also possible to override @POST request here 
    public Collection<Customer> getCustomers(){
        // more logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a method to you repository interface.

```
class CustomerRepository {

    public List<Customer> findRecent();      

}
```

Given method will be exported under `/customers/findRecent`. You can tweak the paths using `@RestResource` annotation.

Talking about your second case, e.g. *@GET customers/:id/photo*,t that is handled transparently by the Spring Data Rest, meaning, that if your entity `Customer` has a `photo` association, it is exported under that url out of the box.